# Force Android screen to remain off until power button is pressed?

Tags: screen, standby

I run Android 5.0.1. I'm finding the screen a bit iffy, in that it doesn't remain off until I press the power button, but comes on randomly. There are plenty of apps to make it come on without the power button using other methods, but I want it to remain off until I press the power button.

Somehow, say I turn it off, then go to put the phone down on the table, but it comes on during the process. I would like to avoid that. I haven't been able to find any settings to accomplish this. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I'm now finding that the issue only happens when the device is plugged into its charger. When standalone, the problem does not occur, only when plugged in.

Comment: Which phone do you have?

Comment: I have HTC One M8 on Verizon

Comment: Do you have a custom rom installed? There is a post on XDA, someone with the same issue. There was an app called "ROMDashboard Developer Tool" installed on their phone and apparently that was the issue for this user.

Comment: No, no custom ROM. It's all stock. Not rooted or anything.